# Oracle Database performance is slow

Tags: database, oracle

Overall Database performance is slow in on of our production environment.

Herewith I have attached the statspack reports of two time periods generated on 15/02/16 between 09.00AM - 02.00PM and 03.00PM - 07.00PM GMT .

DB details:

Oracle 11g 11.2.0.3.0 - Standard Edition

OS memory: 11.2GB

the current database SGA and PGA size is : 
sga_max_size : 5G 
sga_target : 5G 
pga_aggregate_target : 1G 
db_cache_size : 2080M 
memory_max_target : 0 
memory_target : 0

Please advice on this.

Ram

Comment: I don't see any statspack reports attached?

Answer (score 0):

Run an AWR Report using `dbms_workload_repository` (for an html output use [AWR_DIFF_REPORT_HTML function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_wkrpos.htm#i1004015)) or Oracle Enterprise Manager and check what's the things which are taking the most db time / cpu time / io ops etc.

There can be dozens of different causes for your not-that-specific issue.

Regarding the SGA/PGA specifically -
you can also just query `gv$sga_target_advice`, `gv$pga_target_advice` and check if there's a lack of memory in some of the pools (the more advanced and precise option is `gv$sga_resize_ops`).